# WordPress Popularity Score relative to all posts (score views, shares and comments)

Tags: wordpress, popularity

I am trying to find a solution to score my posts in an effort to visually represent how "hot" they are, relative to other posts, or relative to a score of 1.

I have views, total shares and comments available as inputs, but I'm unsure what approach to take to score my posts against each other, so I have a relative score out of 1, i.e. .6, .8 etc.

I came across the following in my search for a solution

http://www.evanmiller.org/rank-hotness-with-newtons-law-of-cooling.html

and

[Hot content algorithm / score with time decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653545/hot-content-algorithm-score-with-time-decay)

Any ideas on how I can approach this? The posts should also take into account time, as I have several years worth of posts.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting 5 scoring periods, then scoring each post against the highest score found in that period. The score takes in social media, post views and comments. Provides a good rating!