# Updated timestamp sort decay algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, ranking

I need to rank a number of posts by their `updated_at` timestamp but I need the rank to have some sort of exponential decay after the post has been updated 6 hours after `created_at` until 2 weeks at which point it breaks even and doesn't change rank.

When the post is created, `updated_at` is set to the timestamp as `created_at` to kick-off sorting.

I looked at [Hot content algorithm / score with time decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653545/hot-content-algorithm-score-with-time-decay) which is along the lines of what I'm looking for but I need the rank to have a precision similar to the `updated_at` timestamp.

The reason I need this is so that posts which were created a while back yet updated recently won't be shown higher than posts that were recently created.

Comment: I think, once you've stated this question clearly enough for someone to answer it correctly, you'll have answered it correctly.

Comment: How should I further clarify it?

Comment: What do you mean by "drop off" the rank? So you only want to rank first all that were created in the past 6 hours based on `updated_at`, then after that you rank the rest based on `created_at` field?

Comment: what kind of rank has a precision? drop off how much, in what range? How should a file updated after a longer interval be ranked against a file created later, and what procedure did you use to arrive at that?

Comment: I think by precision he is referring to online ranking algorithm, where the time keeps ticking and the ranks need to be updated every millisecond (or every short amount of time)

Comment: Essentially, the posts are sorted by their `updated_at` timestamp but I need to push them down lower in the post results as the are updated later and later than their creation time so that newly created posts can show up on top.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a time-exponential-decay score? That seems rather unlikely. Instead, you want to sort by a modified `updated_at`:

```
def updated_val(item):
    if(item.updated_at - item.created_at > 6 hours)
        return item.created_at + 6 hours
    else
        return item.updated_at
```

If the item has been edited within 6 hours we return the unmodified `updated_at`. However, if the item has been edited *after* six hours, we return simply the last valid `updated_at` value, which would be `created_at + 6 hours`.

If you have something like an additional score function, you can simply plug it into this solution:

```
def updated_val_scored(item):
    if(item.updated_at - item.created_at > 6 hours)
        return score(item.created_at + 6 hours)
    else
        return score(item.updated_at)
```

Comment: The post gets updated only when someone comments on it. For that case I would still like it to show up on the first page but pulled down based on how long the original post was created (edited or not).

Comment: @PaulKonova: So you want to sort by creation time, but show only on the front page if the post has been edited in the last six hours? Then your current question isn't really complete. Add some examples/scenarios.